# How to check which Tensorflow version is compatible to Tensorflow Model Garden?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-model-garden

In order to use a pre-trained model with Tensorflow, we clone the [Model Garden for TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models), then choose a model in Model Zoo, for example, [Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md): *EfficientDet D0 512x512*.

Is there anyway to detect the **right version** of Tensorflow, e.g. `2.7.0`, or `2.7.1`, or `2.8.0`, that will **surely work** with the aforementioned setup?

The documentation (`README.md`) doesn't seem to mention this requirement. Maybe it is implied somehow?

I checked `setup.py` for Object Detection, but there is still no clue!

```
\models\research\object_detection\packages\tf2\setup.py
```

```
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    # Required for apache-beam with PY3
    'avro-python3',
    'apache-beam',
    'pillow',
    'lxml',
    'matplotlib',
    'Cython',
    'contextlib2',
    'tf-slim',
    'six',
    'pycocotools',
    'lvis',
    'scipy',
    'pandas',
    'tf-models-official>=2.5.1',
    'tensorflow_io',
    'keras'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a formal/quick way to determine the **right Tensorflow version, given a specific** [Model Garden](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) version, `master` branch. However, here is my workaround:

1. In the `REQUIRED_PACKAGES` above, we see `tf-models-official>=2.5.1`.
2. Checking the [package history](https://pypi.org/project/tf-models-official/#history) on pypi.org, the latest version, as of 03.02.2022, is `2.8.0`.
3. So when installing this `\models\research\object_detection\packages\tf2\setup.py` file, `pip` will naturally fetch the latest version of `tf-models-official`, which is `2.8.0`, thanks to `>=` symbol.
4. However, given `tf-models-official`, `v2.8.0`, its required packages are defined in `tf-models-official-2.8.0\tf_models_official.egg-info\requires.txt` (Note: download the package and extract it, using the [link](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/04/23e13e689d5da33e5210476862f08c496df16d2a0cb2803ebd1fb6c81436/tf-models-official-2.8.0.tar.gz).)
5. Here, we find out:

```
tensorflow~=2.8.0
```

...meaning the required Tensorflow version is `2.8.*`.

This may not be desired, e.g. in CoLab, currently, the version is `2.7.0`.

6. To workaround, we should use `tf-models-official`, `v2.7.0`. Notice it matches the Tensorflow version. In this version `2.7.0`'s `requires.txt`, we should see `tensorflow>=2.4.0`, which is already satisfied by CoLab's default Tensorflow version (`2.7.0`).
7. To make this workaround possible, the `\models\research\object_detection\packages\tf2\setup.py` should be modified from, e.g. `'tf-models-official>=2.5.1'` to `'tf-models-official==2.7.0'`.

**Caveat**: I think this hack doesn't affect the functionality of the Object Detection API because it originally demands any `tf-models-official` >= `2.5.1`. We just simply fix it to `==2.7.0` instead.